# Best way to set up the connection setting

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection, connection-string

I am new to windows forms programming and I was wondering what would be the best way to create like a `connectionstring.config`  (i dont know how to do this) I have seens it , its like an xml giving all the information to connect to the database, in my case I am connecting to a MySql database. I would like to have so i could do something like this  (I KNOW THIS IS WRONG BUT YOU GET MY IDEA):

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection
(Someconfiguration.thatconnects.toMyXMLOrSomething["MyXMLFile]);
```

something like that, i know i am probably too far from what it is.. but I have seen this somewhere and i think its clean, instead of putting the data connection information everywhere i need it.

so a few questions:

- How do i create that xml file in VS2010?
- Where do I place that file?
- How should I call it in the functions where i am using it?.

I would really appreciate all the possible help as I am learning and would like to keep everything separate and clean like this.

Thank you for your help and valuable time to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them in a specific node inside your **app.config** file.

Here's the MSDN documentation for adding the app.config file to your project and it includes adding connection strings:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243192(v=vs.100).aspx

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;" />
    </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

You can then use the built in .NET ConfigurationManager class to pull it out:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: This is not a web project its a Windows Forms :) thank you though

Comment: It applies to *both*, use the app.config, I updated the post to exclude the word web.

Comment: thank you one last question, if i am using MySql, that connection string format would work? just curious

Comment: Yes, that is MySQL format. You could also see here for more info on that: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: and one very last i promise, if my password is empty can i just leave it as password=?

Comment: Not sure, but you could just try it out. Possibly just exclude the whole password part.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project - `Add -> New Item...` `- General - Application Configuration File` (app.config). You can add a `connectionStrings` section there.

See ["Connection Strings and Configuration Files"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details.

If you *really* want to put you connection strings in a separate file you can set this up as well within your app.config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

- How do i create that xml file in VS2010?

> Add a new `app.config` file in the root of your project.

- Where do I place that file?

> Normally the root of your application.

- How should I call it in the functions where i am using it?

  string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
  string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key];

Answer (score 0):

Put in in `app.config`. It should already be in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Microsoft documentation on the topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationConnectionString" connectionString="YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING" providerName="System.Data.PROVIDER_NAME"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```